# Cocos2D-js : Put the camera to the center of the map

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm using a isometric tiledmap in a game.
And I'm don't know how to center the camera to the center of the map.
Is there any function or tutorial on this that I've missed?
Any guidance will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function, but you can use setPosition(x, y) function of you map(its base class is CCNode) to put it in the right place and make the "camera" to the center of the map.

For example, if your map size is (w1, h1), and window size (cc.director.getWinSize()) equals (w2, h2). Assume w1 >= w2 and h1 >= h2.
Assume the anchor point of map is cc.p(0,0).
So we can put the map in center by

```
map.setPosition(-(w1 - w2)/2, -(h1 - h2)/2)
```

To keep the map in center continuously, you can put this code in your game's update() function.